# Help to identify the screw standard

Tags: electrical-panel, screws

I have a screw that is used to fasten electrical-panel door. Now the wall got thicker and I need longer screw to fasten the door. I measured the size of the screw and tried to order same diameter screws from local shop. The problem is that threading was different and ordered screw did not fit. I was not able find the actual screw standard.

Thread (outer) diameter: `4mm`

Thread pitch: `2mm`

Thread length: `13mm`

Thread count: `7`

Head diameter: `6mm`

Some photos:

[image: thread pitch]
[image: thread length]
[image: head]
[image: bottom]
[image: thread]

*Update:*
Model of the box: [Hager Volta](https://hager.com/de-ch/katalog/produkt/vu24na-kleinvvoltaupv2x12pleip30)
[image: panel]

Comment: It is not metric thread, neither SAE. Self drilling screw is not standardized. Looks like it for plastic.

Comment: Yup, it is for fastening the metal door to plastic.

Comment: need pictures of the enclosure.

Comment: Hi @RadioSpace, I updated the question with the model and image of the box.

Comment: Most of the images are broken (the SSL certificate is wrong, and the site tells me to log in) - you might have a way to reupload them, in order to benefit future visitors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whoa, no, you can't do that.

You can't let wall materials squeeze in between panel and door.

That's not an approved (or approve-able) installation of the panel. It goes against manufacturer instructions and that of the testing lab which confirmed the panel safe.

The hole in your new wall layer needs somewhat larger than the panel *cover*. So the panel cover can join to the panel properly as designed.

Feel free to cover the whole thing with a tasteful cabinet door, if you have a problem with the aesthetics of that.   That's just tearing a page from Victorian era design, which regularly did that to cover utilities.

Comment: That actually is a good idea. You mean to attach materials directly to the cabinet door? Or make another door on top of this door?

Comment: Cover your panel, not attach to it. The answer was clear.

Comment: @AndriusPetrauskis I meant an outer door that opens to reveal the unmodified electrical panel. Like a cabinet door.